# How can I mimic the VS 2012 "publish webSite" from command line (or in tfs automated build)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I have a WebSite which is locally in a folder on my computer. It doesn't have a .csproj - just all the files in a folder. I want to do the publish website in the automated build which is basically as doing it in command line using msbuild.exe and\or msdeploy.exe and\or aspnet_compiler.exe and/or anything else.

If you want to create a project like so you can create an empty solution, add -> new website (select filesystem on the buttom in the combobox), add an empty class file, right click on the website line in the solution explorer, under the solution line, Publish website, there you need to create a new profile- really easy- basically choosing "file-system" and then publish.

I'm running on VS2012, update 4.

Answer (score 1):

if you pass in an MSbuild argument of

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=PROFILENAME
```

it should do the same as publishing from VS if your profile is set up correctly

> EDIT

Sorry just had to run one of these through to see what happens

when you check in a Website to TFS it creates a websites folder.

[image: web site source control structure]

you can then map your build to this folder.

instead of mapping the build to a sln file you can point to the publishproj file, this gets created when you create the publish profile. this tells the build what to do

[image: build args for a web site build]

in this i had set the publish location to be c:\publish and after the build i had the output in a folder called c:\publish.

the generated publishproj file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

***********************************************************************************************
website.publishproj

WARNING: DO NOT MODIFY this file, it is used for the web publish process.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

***********************************************************************************************
-->

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>10.0.30319</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{f17a9da4-9b68-41e4-ab73-5ac72898b384}</ProjectGuid>
    <SourceWebPhysicalPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
    <SourceWebVirtualPath>/WebSite1</SourceWebVirtualPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <SourceWebProject>http://localhost:61874</SourceWebProject>
    <SourceWebMetabasePath>/IISExpress/7.5/LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT</SourceWebMetabasePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- for VS2010 we need to use 10.5 but for VS2012+ we should use VisualStudioVersion -->
    <WebPublishTargetsVersion Condition=" '$(WebPublishTargetsVersion)' =='' and '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == 10.0 ">10.5</WebPublishTargetsVersion>
    <WebPublishTargetsVersion Condition=" '$(WebPublishTargetsVersion)'=='' ">$(VisualStudioVersion)</WebPublishTargetsVersion>

    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(WebPublishTargetsVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <_WebPublishTargetsPath Condition=" '$(_WebPublishTargetsPath)'=='' ">$(VSToolsPath)</_WebPublishTargetsPath>
    <AssemblyFileVersion Condition="'$(AssemblyFileVersion)' == ''">1.0.0.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    <AssemblyVersion Condition="'$(AssemblyVersion)' == ''">1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyFileVersion">
      <Value>$(AssemblyFileVersion)</Value>
    </AssemblyAttributes>
    <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyVersion">
      <Value>$(AssemblyVersion)</Value>
    </AssemblyAttributes>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(_WebPublishTargetsPath)\Web\Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it seems to be working only for web-project projects and not for webSite project (I don't have the *.csproj file that it needs). when I did it on my the solution file it just did a regular build of the solution.

Comment: sorry, have run through a sample project now and have added the steps to get it to work

Comment: I have many more projects to build so it can't be done like so because the other projects are compiled as Dlls etc. I will check and see if it works on that project alone and if it'll work i'll check what the parameters that the RunMsbuil Activity is getting and will try and work with that. My subscription to VS trail has ended, I will get it fixed this week hopefully and will let you know how it goes...